# Mutually Inclusive Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

I need to express the idea that, "if one of these fields exists, then so does the other."
Naturally, if these two fields are peers in the same scope, then it becomes difficult to represent that idea.

For example, given the type of a `Pipeline`:

```
type Status = 'running' | 'finished' | 'error' | 'inherited'
type Pipeline = Array<{
    name: string
    status: Status
    parent?: string // dirty. only 'inherited' needs this.
}>
```

How would you represent the idea that the `parent` field must be defined if `status='inherited'`?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what exactly your use case is, you can also consider conditional types, something like

```js
type Status = 'running' | 'finished' | 'error' | 'inherited'

type Pipeline<S extends Status> = Array<{
    name: string
    status: S
    parent: S extends 'inherited' ? string : never
}>

declare const a: Pipeline<'inherited'>
declare const b: Pipeline<'finished'>
a[0].parent // string
b[0].parent // never
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking in terms of "mutually including" these options together, it is better to think of it as "exiling them away" from the others.

```
type Status = 'running' | 'finished' | 'error' | 'inherited'
type Pipeline = Array<{
    name: string
    status: Exclude<Status, 'inherited'>
} | {
    name: string
    status: 'inherited'
    parent: string
}>
```

Of course, for more complicated schemas, this has the disadvantage that you now need to repeat many fields.

To handle this, you can gather the common fields and inherit from them using the `&` operator.

```
type Common = {
    name: string
    lots: string
    of: string
    metadata: string
}
type Pipeline = Array<Common & ({
    status: Exclude<Status, 'inherited'>
} | {
    status: 'inherited'
    parent: string
})>
```

While it will assist in type checking, the abstraction makes the actual type more opaque in the error inspection window.